# Text after subfigure skips second column of the subfigure in a two column document

Tags: subfloats

My code is below. This gives me four figures one on top of each other, occupying one column (left) of a two column document as desired. My problem is that the text after these figures does not fill the right column as expected rather it skips it to start in a new page. Anyone to help please?

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Measured RSS from user devices at all azimuth positions}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{ExpMeasuredRSS}}
    \label{fig:ExpMeasuredRSS}

    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Experimental estimated DoA of users}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{Exp_AoA_SystemJournal2}}
    \label{fig:ExperimentalResultAoA}

    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Measured RSS from user devices at all azimuth positions}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{SimExpRange}}
    \label{fig:SimExpRange}

    \subfigure[\footnotesize{Experimental estimated DoA of users}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{ExpUserCluster2.pdf}}
    \label{fig:ExpUserCluster2}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Especially use example images and not images only you have (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: The title should be as short and meaningful as possible. Therefore I shortened it a bit.

Comment: BTW, figure* does not support [h].  [tp] is fine.  Also, the most likely problem is a large unbreakable block in the text.